# Enviar datos a rest "ficticio" JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que me pide que envie datos a un rest fictitio. Ya que el rest es ficticio no funcionara el envio pero, me gustaría saber si el código que he hecho para esa supuesta subida de datos es correcta.

**con el botón "send" deben enviarse los datos a un servicio REST ficticio.**

```
 jQuery(".send.btn").click(function(evento){
    var lista = [];
    console.log(nombre);
    console.log(edad);
    $( ".list li" ).each(function( index ) {
      console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
      lista.push(jQuery( this ).text());
    });
    console.log(lista);

    const URL = 'https://restficticio.com/posts/';
    const data = {
        name:nombre,
        age:edad,
        list:lista
    }

    $.post(URL, data, function(data, status) {
        console.log('${data} and status is ${status}');
    });
});
```

Comment: Podrías usar un servidor *mock* para realizar las pruebas. Puedes probar con [mocky.io](https://www.mocky.io) o con [beeceptor.com](https://beeceptor.com). Así como los mencionados hay varias opciones. Saludos

Comment: Que bien!! No sabia la existencia de esa herramienta. Muy Util!!